# touchesBegan not working inside UIScrollView Swift 5

Tags: ios, ios13, swift5

I know this question has been asked 100 times on stackoverflow but I simply cannot find an answer to this. I have a scrollerView, and inside that there is a scrollerContentView.. how am i supposed to capture the taps that occur inside the scrollerContentView or ScrollerView or it doesn't matter.. ive tried implementing many of the override functions ive found for example

```
   let scrollViewTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scrollViewTapped(_:)))
    @objc func scrollViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("UIScrollView was tapped.")
    }
```

outside of the ViewDidLoad

and

```
      scrollViewTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        scrollViewTapGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
        scrollViewTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        scrollerView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollViewTapGestureRecognizer)
```

inside the view did load....
none of the answers on stack overflow work.

Comment: Are you sure your scroll view is actually there? Try changing its background color to verify you’re actually tapping on it. You may also need to disable user interaction on scrollerContentView because it might be blocking touches to your scrollerView.

Answer (score 0):

there this code will work fine when you need to capture tap events in scrollView.
This will only call when there is a tap gesture (Click on scrollView) on scrollView. It won't call when user scrolls through the content.
If you want to capture when user scrolls through scrollview then you need to implement.

`func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)  { print("Scrolled") }` This delegate method. Remember to give scrollView delegate or this won't work.

Hope this helps Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Im not sure how to exactly give the delegate to the scrolllView, can you please show me how this would be done?

Comment: just add this in your viewDidload method :- `scrollerView.delegate = self `

Do upvote and accept this answer if it did help you